# Pivot week numbers from Google Sheets and Google Analytics

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

Google Sheets, on using `WEEKNUM` or `ISOWEEKNUM` displays first year weeks without zero, like `20201`, `20202` and so on.

Google Analytics, its metric `ga:YearWeek` delivers week numbers of first year weeks with zero, like `202001`, `202002` and so on.

I have in one column week numbers given by `ISOWEEKNUM`, and in another table some data based on GA's `ga:YearWeek`. How can i pivot them smartly? Currently both week numbers don't match.

---

**PS**: i've tried to add a zero to week numbers, don't having it on the beginning, with

`=IF((REGEXMATCH("A2";"^[0-9]{1}$"));(CONCAT("0";A2));"A2")`

It works in one cell, but i can't pull the formula to the bottom - everywhere remains A2 because of `""`. And without `""`, with formula like

`=IF((REGEXMATCH(A2;"^[0-9]{1}$"));(CONCAT("0";A2));"A2")`

i run into an issue

```
Error
Function REGEXMATCH parameter 1 expects text values. But '28' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text.
```

**PPS**: i'm on german Google Sheets - there should be `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: Got rid of the `REGEXMATCH` issue with `=IF((REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2);"^[1-9]{1}$"));(CONCAT("0";"A2"));A2)`. But a really smart solution for the whole task isn't there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A1),(IF(WEEKNUM(A1)<10, CONCATENATE("0",WEEKNUM(A1)), WEEKNUM(A1))))
```

It takes the `year` from the date specified and adds the `week`: if the number of the `week` is less than 10, then it adds a `0`, else, it leaves it as it is.

[image]

Also, you can drag the formula to the bottom so you can use it in all the cells in the column you want.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,
 YEAR(A1:A)&IF(WEEKNUM(A1:A)<10, "0"&WEEKNUM(A1:A), WEEKNUM(A1:A))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution to concatenating is using `&`, and using the `TEXT` function to add the leading zero like this:

```
=TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1),"00")
```

So, the full formula to transform `01/01/2020` into `202001` would be:

```
=YEAR(A1)&TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1),"00")
```